# Is there a command to convert a directory of .sid files to .mp3 files?

Tags: directory, mp3

I am looking for a command to convert a directory of .sid files to .mp3 files. Thank you.
(Sid files are named after the Sound Interface Chip found in Commodore 64 personal computers.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but you need two conversion utilities: [SID to WAV](http://www.vgmpf.com/Wiki/index.php?title=SID_to_WAV) and [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/) ;
this approach needs two passes, first in wav format and then in mp3.
You did not specify a target language, but a loop over all `*.sid` files in your directory is very simple to do, in Bash or Powershell.